# Converting 2 bytes to signed int

Tags: c#, int

Is their any way to convert 2 bytes to signed int? I know we can convert a byte to signed int in following way

```
byte B1= 0xFF;
int r = Convert.ToSbyte((sbyte)B1);
```

but what about 2 bytes to signed int? For example -260 is 0xFC, 0xFE

Comment: If this is a communication protocol, you need to know the endian order of the achitecture first. Also, 2 byte signed integer is a `short` (or `Int16`), not `int` (which is `Int32`) in .NET.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case of one byte, just *assign*:

```
byte B1 = 0xFF;
int r = B1;
```

In case of two bytes - add *shift* and assign:

```
byte B1 = 0xFE;
byte B2 = 0xFC;

int r = (B1 << 8) | B2;
```

in case `Int16` is wanted then cast:

```
// -260
short s = unchecked((short) ((B1 << 8) | B2));
```

Comment: OP probably wants a signed `Int16`.

Comment: good old binary operators, for sure most efficient than any converter class :)

Answer (score 10):

Assuming the first byte is the msb:

```
byte b1 = 0xff;
byte b2 = 0xff;
var test = BitConverter.ToInt16(new byte[] { b1, b2 }, 0);
```

Otherwise:

```
byte b1 = 0xff;
byte b2 = 0xff;
var test = BitConverter.ToInt16(new byte[] { b2, b1 }, 0);
```

Edit: "signed"

Comment: OP probably wants a signed `Int16`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [BitConverter class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and its ToInt32() method.

Comment: That will convert to unsigned integer

Comment: @prattom BitConverter.ToInt32: *Returns a 32-bit signed integer converted from four bytes at a specified position in a byte array.*

Comment: sorry not unsigned integer but Bitconverter returns positive integer instead to negative integer for ex. 0xFC, 0xFE is returned as 65276 if I use BitConverter class while it should -260

Comment: ToInt32(array<Byte>^, Int32)   Returns a 32-bit signed integer converted from four bytes at a specified position in a byte array. you should use this.

Comment: @prattom that's becaue you used ToInt32 and only sent two bytes, an int32 has it's negative bit at the most significant bit of the dword, so there's no negative for two bytes, use ToInt16()